# Fast and compact way to check if the vector is binary

Tags: c++, vector, stl

What's the most efficient and compact way of checking whether all elements of `std::vector<int> x` are binary?

I'm looking for something more efficient AND/OR compact than just iterating over the elements, comparing them to 0 and 1 and stopping after first non-0 or non-1 element is found. Perhaps, there is no way to do it faster, but more compact and nice - possible.

Comment: What do you mean that `double`s are "binary"?  Do you mean you want to detect if they represent values near 0 and near 1?  Because equals doesn't work so great with floating point types.

Comment: @MooingDuck, doubles that actually contain integer values usually don't cause problems. What I want to know is what is the purpose behind this question? P.S. The question was just edited to say `int` instead of `double`.

Comment: @MooingDuck, edited question with `vector<int>`

Comment: @MarkRansom: `double`s often don't contain integer values even when people are "sure" they are.

Comment: @MarkRansom, the purpose is to determine whether the matrix is binary or not

Comment: @MarkRansom While that's generally true for small enough values (say < 2^53 or so for doubles) the value 0 can get very nasty depending on you come up with the value.

Comment: @user2028058 Try showing us what code you have, then if you're just asking for a more compact solution perhaps there's something we can do for you

Comment: But in case of doubles, you can still compare them to 1.0, right?

Comment: Use all_of in the <algorithm> library.

Comment: @CrazyCasta, are you talking about negative zeros? Anyway this is clearly off topic now so I'm shutting up.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well I was actually talking about very small numbers if you do something like sin(pi) for instance. I agree, we are getting off topic though, so that's all I have to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want is to check wether a container only contain zeroes and ones?

In that case you can use e.g. [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with a suitable predicate to check it:

```
std::vector<int> x{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };

if(std::all_of(std::begin(x), std::end(x), [] (int value) {
    return value == 0 || value == 1;
})) {
    std::cout << "Only contain 0's and 1's." << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `std::find_if()` with a suitable lambda:

```
if (std::any_of(x.begin(), x.end(),
                [](unsigned int v) { return v & ~1u; })) {
    std::cout << "not all values are binary\n";
}
```